# Python: Controlling using if

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, controls

I have this code:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if True and True and True and not False:
        print "Kevin stinkt"
    elif 10 < 4:
        print "Justin stinkt"
    else:
        print "herb-wuerzig"
```

When I `print the_flying_circus` I get `Kevin stinkt` printed, `None` as a return. I would need `False` as return for an online tutorial. Why do I get `None`, and how can I achieve an `True`?

Comment: *"I get Kevin stinkt as a return"* - **incorrect**. The function *prints* `'Kevin stinkt'` and *returns* `None`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7664779/3001761.

Answer (score 2):

`None` is the return value of the function. A function that finishes without an explicit `return` statement will return `None`.

In response to your additional question:

If you want the function to return true, put

```
return True
```

at the end. If you want it to return false, put

```
return False
```

at the end.

Comment: okay, i see the difference. how do i get the function to return true (false)?

Comment: @bngschmnd: Exactly like it sounds: `return True`.

Comment: @bngschmnd: But why do you want to return True anyway? What are you going to do with that value? That'll just meant that when you type `the_flying_circus()` in the interpreter, your function will print out `Kevin stinkt`, and then the interpreter will print out `True` underneath that.

Comment: i need that for an online python tutorial `# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True`

Answer (score 1):

The function returns `None` if it does not return anything else, hence you first print inside the function and then you print the `None` that was returned.

If you either exchange your `print` statements with `return` or just call `the_flying_circus()` instead of `print the_flying_circus()` you will get the expected result.

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if True and True and True and not False:
        return "Kevin stinkt"
    elif 10 < 4:
        return "Justin stinkt"
    else:
        return "herb-wuerzig"
```

Then you can run the function and print the returned value:

```
print the_flying_circus()
```

Or you can do:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if True and True and True and not False:
        print "Kevin stinkt"
    elif 10 < 4:
        print "Justin stinkt"
    else:
        print "herb-wuerzig"
```

And just call the function without printing the returned value:

```
the_flying_circus()
```

Comment: tried `#Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus():
    if True and True and True and not False:    
        return true
    elif 5 < 10:
        return true
    else:
        return true` and `# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus():
    if True and True and True and not False:    
        return true
    elif 5 < 10:
        return true
    else:
        return false` - didnt  seem to work at all?

Comment: It is very difficult to read without indentation, but at least you need to use `True` and `False` with a capital first letter.

Answer (score 0):

The code needed is the following:

`# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus(antwort):
    if antwort > 5:

        print "H"
    elif antwort < 5:
        print "A"
    else:
        print "I"
    return True`

what ever input I give, `the_flying_circus` always returns `True`