# Printing "none" after joining a list

Tags: python

I have a class called deck, it stores a list of integers, I need to print those integers so I used

```
def printdeck(self):
    print(" ".join(map(str,self.deck)))
```

It works and all but it returns "none" after use. I'd like it not to print "none" but I've no idea how to stop that. Any ideas?

Comment: return an empty string

Comment: Are you printing the return value too? The code shown here does **not** print `None`.

Comment: Either return a string (`return " ".join(map(str,self.deck))`), which you then print `(print(deck.printdeck())`, *or* just leave the printing to the method and ignore the return value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My guess is that this is being used in a shell, and thus he is seeing "None" being printed after calling the function.

Comment: @RushyPanchal: the Python interactive interpreter does not print expression results if they produce `None`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/python-what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return or it's duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, did not realize this. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of [Why is "None" printed after my function's output?](/q/7053652).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're not actually returning anything, so the function defaults to returning `None`.

A better alternative is to return your joined string, and then print that result:

```
def getdeck(self):
    return " ".join(map(str,self.deck))

print(getdeck())
```

Note that if you keep your function in this form:

```
def printdeck(self):
    print(" ".join(map(str,self.deck)))
```

it will work as you intend to, but it returns `None`. If you print the return value, then you will see `None` being printed.

Comment: You could keep it the second way but return an empty string to avoid returning None.