# None after printing instance variables

Tags: python

Why do I get `None` after each result of the `print` statement?

I have never come across this while using the `print` statement or class instantiation...

Where is `None` coming from?

​

```
class Enemy:

    life = 3

    def attack(self):
        print("ouch!")
        self.life -= 1

    def checkLife(self):
        if (self.life <= 0):
            print('dead!')
        else:
            print( str(self.life) + " lives left..." )


e1 = Enemy()

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 3 lives left...
# None

print( e1.attack() )
# ouch!
# None

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 2 lives left...
# None
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Enemy:

    life = 3

def attack(self):
    print("ouch!")
    self.life -= 1

def checkLife(self):
    if (self.life <= 0):
        print('dead!')
    else:
        print( str(self.life) + " lives left..." )


e1 = Enemy()

e1.checkLife()


e1.attack()


e1.checkLife()
```

you dont need the print infront of the function calls, as there is a print function inside every function, it will print what you want to see, the function itself returns None as there is nothing to return, thus printing it gives you None

Answer (score 1):

You're `print`ing the return value of functions that don't return a value.

```
print( e1.checkLife() )
# 3 lives left...        This is printed from within the function
# None        checkLife() returns None, and you print it here
```

Answer (score 1):

All Python functions return something—`None` if you use just `return` (or no return at all).  Don’t `print` it if you don’t want to see it.  In an interactive session, the interpreter automatically prints the value of each expression *unless* it is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class, every method of your class (functions of your class) should have correct identation. In your code ***attack, checkLife*** are interpreted like independent functions. That's the reason when you try to call checkLife you get:

> AttributeError: Enemy instance has no attribute 'checkLife'

Also you must define a constructor for your class, a special kind of function which is responsible to create your object properly. In your case your enemy's life should be initialized to 3. You should define this attribute in your constructor, so your object can have it. That's the reason *self.life* works.

*self.life* refers to your object's (self) attribute with the name *life*.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 3

    def attack(self):
        print("ouch!")
        self.life -= 1

    def checkLife(self):
        if (self.life <= 0):
            print('dead!')
        else:
            print( str(self.life) + " lives left..." )


e1 = Enemy()

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 3 lives left...
# None

print( e1.attack() )
# ouch!
# None

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 2 lives left...
# None
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This happened while I was copying my code and pasting it into this post. I will edit it now...

Answer (score 0):

> All Python functions return the value `None` unless there is an explicit **`return`** statement with a value other than `None`. Instead, the value `None` will be returned.

So the second print is actually returning the results of the functions which are both `None`. The first print inside the function is just enough.
Or you update you function to have explicit `return` and then print the returned values as follow:

```
class Enemy:

    life = 3

    def attack(self):
       print("ouch!")
       self.life -= 1
       return self.life

    def checkLife(self):
        if (self.life <= 0):
            return 'dead!'
        else:
            return str(self.life) + " lives left..."


e1 = Enemy()

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 3 lives left...

print( e1.attack() )
# ouch!
# 2

print( e1.checkLife() )
# 2 lives left...
```