# Iterating two arrays in python with two different conditions

Tags: python, arrays

How do I iterate two sets of array with two different conditions?
I am using iris data and trying to classify if it is versicolour or vigrinica.

```
array = dataframe.values
petalLength = array[50:,2]
petalWidth = array[50:,3]
```

I'm trying to iterate two arrays, but not getting the results I need.

```
def decision(petalLength, petalWidth):
    for x in petalLength:
        for y in petalWidth:
            if x < 4.8 and y < 1.8:
                print("Versicolour")
            else:
                print("Virginica")
```

Results for example:

```
petal Length is 4.7 and petal Width is 1.5 the answer should be Versicolour
petal Length is 4.7 and petal width is 1.9 the answer should be Virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is pair-wise iteration, which you would generally do with `zip`:

```
for x, y in zip(petalLength, petalWidth):
    if x < 4.8 and y < 1.8:
        print("Versicolour")
    else:
        print("Virginica")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have nested for loops which gives you N^2 results, when you only want to do the operation once.

Every inner loop is run len(petalLength) times... Which compares every petalWidth to every petalLength instead of doing it in pairs.

```
def decision(petalLength, petalWidth):
    for i in range(len(petalLength)):
        if petalLength[i] < 4.8 and petalWidth[i] < 1.8:
            print("Versicolour")
        else:
            print("Virginica")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Addition to schwobaseggl's answer, [use `return` instead of `print`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return):

```
def decision(petalLength, petalWidth):
    for x, y in zip(petalLength, petalWidth):
        if x < 4.8 and y < 1.8:
            return "Versicolour"
        else:
            return "Virginica"
```

Then now:

```
print(decision(petalLength,petalWidth))
```

Will return as desired output,

But previously, it will output desired output, then an other line having `None`

Same with Aleksei Maide's answer.