# to change the value of instance variable

Tags: python, instance-variables

I want to print name as tanya but since `self.name = None` has been assigned in constructor it is printing `None`. So how to get tanya printed when the check function gets called:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def price(self):
        self.name = "tanya"

    def check(self):
        print(self.price())

a=A()
a.check()
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor isn't the problem

`print(self.price())` is going to print `None` because [you are printing the result of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return).

It **then** sets `self.name="tanya"` after printing, but you are ignoring it

Instead, I think you want

```
a=A()
a.price()
print(a.name)
```

and forget the check function

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=None

    def price(self):
        self.name="tanya"
        return self.name

    def check(self):
        print(self.price())

a=A()
a.check()
```

You just have to add the `return` statement in the `price` function, and you're done!