# How to use Python function in for loop

Tags: python

I want to read Python function output line by line without printing None object on screen

Created function called `server_array`, now using same function in for loop:

```
for i in [server_array()]:
    print (i)
```

But it's printing `None` too:

```
(venv) C:\myproject>python API\execution.py
/api/deployments/1360294004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360332004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360356004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360368004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360376004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360388004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360392004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360408004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360418004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360426004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360430004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360433004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360447004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360448004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360452004/server_arrays
/api/deployments/1360473004/server_arrays
None
```

Comment: Shown code prints what `server_array()` returns. The problem lies in this function.

Comment: Why did you expect that it wouldn't? Most likely `server_array` prints things itself and doesn't return anything, in which case maybe just **don't print `i`** (or, for that matter, don't build a single-element list, iterate over it and print each one thing in it. Just write `server_array()`). Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7664779/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i agree with you. So , is there any way to use for loop again on function output ?

Comment: There is *if the function returns something iterable*. None is not iterable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , i have achieved my resonse in below steps :

Used `append` function to print all output in form of list and then `return` the same (to remove none)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
responses = [element for element in server_array() if element is not None]
```

Then either:

```
print(responses)
```

or

```
for curr_response in responses:
    print(curr_response)
```

This will get rid of your `None`, but other commenters are right in that maybe that function shouldn't tack on None to the end of its responses.

Good luck, Happy Coding!