# Why is this function returning no output and only working with print?

Tags: python, function, printing, return

```
def get_formatted_text(first,last):
  full_name=(f'{first} {last}').title()
  return full_name #only works with print. Why?

get_formatted_text('Dick','Long')
```

I don't see any output in my terminal when I do the function call. It works with print function, but I don't understand why print is needed when return will show the output?

Comment: Because `return` is not `print`... not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Well, without `print()` there will be nothing printed. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just RETURNING the value its up to u what u do with the value
and the the brackets r also not required if u r returning the value

```
def get_formatted_text(first, last):
    full_name = f'{first} {last}'.title()
    return full_name  # only works with print. Why?


x = get_formatted_text('Dick', 'Long')
print(x)
```

But if u r returning a value u can even manuplitate like

```
def get_formatted_text(first, last):
     full_name = f'{first} {last}'.title()
     return full_name  # only works with print. Why?


 x = get_formatted_text('Dick', 'Long')
 print(x.lower())
```

Answer (score 2):

Return will not print the value. It only '`returns`' it. When coding directly in the Python terminal it will print the value, but that is the extra capabilities of the terminal, not the `return`. In all other instances, `print` is needed to output to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement returns the title case string. It does not print the element in the console.

After getting the formatted text you may update it as necessary.

```
def get_formatted_text(first,last):
  full_name=(f'{first} {last}').title()
  return full_name

formatted_text = get_formatted_text('john','doe')
print(f"Formatted text with title case: {formatted_text}")
```

**Output:**

```
Formatted text with title case: John Doe
```

**Reference:**

- [What is the formal difference between “print” and “return”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return)

Comment: @IsmailHafeez, the string was in OP's code. Did not check earlier. Updated the string. Thanks.