# I defined a function, but i didn't get any value while I call that function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def number(n):
    x=[]
    for i in range (1,n):
        if i%2==0:
            x=x+[i]
            i=i+1
            
    return(n)
```

In the above code, no error is showing while running, but no value returned

Comment: That just defines the function; you also need to call it

Comment: You also probably meant to return `x` rather than `n`

Comment: Note that the ``i=i+1`` is superfluous. ``i`` will be immediately reassigned to the next value from the ``range``. On a minor note, ``return`` is not a function – its "argument" does not need to be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments section, there are a few things to note:

1. A function needs to be called (in case it was not done), so in your case you have to call the function by `number(10)` for example.
2. Probably you wanted to return `x` instead of `n`.
3. `i = i+1` is not needed since `range()` already returns an iterable, therefore it has to be removed
4. the code in front of `return` does not need to be inside parantheses

Answer (score 0):

you must change your code :

```
def number(n):
    x = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x = x + [i]
            i = i + 1

    return (x) #---> you must return x not n!

print(number(12))
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

**difference between return and print in python** :
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return)