# When returning a list of word and printing it in Python, it only shows letters of the first word in the list

Tags: python

When running the following code:

```
    def my_function(food):
      for x in food:
        return(x)
    fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    name=list(my_function(fruits))
    print(name)
```

I only get ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'], the individual letters of the first word. I expected the whole list.. Even if I am running the code wrong, logically, it would have returned the last word.
Any explanation? I am trying to understand how to pass a list and return same list in an easier manner. Using the same simple code, how can I return the same list.

If I use a regular for loop without the function, I get the whole list words:

```
    food= ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] 
    for x in food: 
      print(x)
```

but here in the function, when you use the same for loop, it only returns the first word.

Comment: Why not just use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)

Comment: You’re returning on the first iteration of the for loop so any other elements of your list won’t get looked at

Comment: `print(x)` is not the same as `return x`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return

Comment: Were you helped by any of the provided answers? If so, please mark one as correct!

Answer (score 2):

> I only get ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'], the individual letters of the first word

This is because you are returning on the first iteration where `x` is the first element in the list.

> logically, it would have returned the last word

No. For this to happen you would need to iterate over the entire list then return:

```
for x in food:
    pass
return x
```

Or just return the last element in `food`: `return food[-1]`

What it seems you are trying to do is possibly get a copy of the list. In this case use `list.copy()`

```
return food.copy()
```

Either that or you are trying to make an iterator over `food` in which case make the function a generator using `yield`:

```
for x in food:
    yield x
```

Or without the loop all together

```
yield from food
```

Or why not just use `iter` as I stated in my comment:

```
name = list(iter(fruits))
```

Comment: Can also `yield from food`, avoiding the `for` loop altogether :)

Comment: Ahh yes, will add that in there

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword tells Python to *immediately* return the value from the function. So `my_function(fruits)` returns the word `"apple"`.

Then you're passing *that* to the `list()` function, which turns the string `"apple"` into a list of characters.

From your post, you say you want to return the same list of items. Do you mean that you want a *copy* of the list? If so, use `food_copy = food.copy()`.

Comment: To loop through the list, you can use the same for loop, and that doesn't return the first word; it returns all the words.

        food= ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
           for x in food:
              return x

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I am explaining why your code returns `["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]`.

Comment: If you use a regular for loop without the function, you would get the whole list words:
 food= ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] for x in food: print(x)
but here in the function, when you use the same for loop, it only returns the first word.

Comment: The `return` keyword outside of a function would be a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant print(x):

Comment: food= ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] for x in food: print(x)

Comment: Well, as I explained in my answer, a `return` statement tells Python to *immediately* return the value from the function. You're only returning the first word ***specifically because you're telling Python to do so.***

Answer (score -1):

As you are using `list` , you might use generators to yield each item or use `return food.copy()` to return copy of the list

```
def my_function(food):
    for x in food:
        yield x


fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
name = list(my_function(fruits))
print(name)
```

Comment: Can I do it with return?

Comment: no , you can not do it with return. Return will return from the method completely and wont execute further items in the list , while yield is generator. You need to see generator , yield in python

Comment: So it won't execute beyond the first element in the list? And why only letters not the whole word.

Comment: see explantion from @ddejohn, I agree with him