# function doesn't return values, code is working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, dictionary

I have this code written down which returns a bunch of ratios
each line works fine when executed alone
however I am having trouble with putting the code inside a function
which should return the values as a dictionary

example of the output: { " less than high school" :0.2 , "high school" :0.39 ...}

```
def education ():
    total = sum (df["CHILDNM"])
    edult12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 1, 0)
    nlt12=sum( edult12["CHILDNM"])
    edu12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 2, 0)
    n12= sum( edu12["CHILDNM"])
    edumt12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 3, 0)
    nmt12=sum( edumt12["CHILDNM"])
    educollege = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 4, 0)
    ncollege = sum( educollege["CHILDNM"])
    lt12ratio = nlt12/total
    edu12ratio = n12 / total
    edumt12ratio = nmt12 / total
    educollegeratio = ncollege/total
    values = print (lt12ratio, edu12ratio,edumt12ratio, educollegeratio )
    print (values)
```

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/

Comment: I think `print(values)` Should be `return values`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the formal difference between "print" and "return"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return)

Comment: Also `print` doesn't return anything, so `values = print(...)` will end up with `values == None`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing the return statement!

Add something like

```
return { "less than high school" :0.2 , "high school" :0.39 }
```

(replace numbers with your actual calculated values)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have any "return" statement. So this means the function will not give back any value.

```
def education ():
    somedict = {'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/'}
    return somedict 


save_return_value = education()
```

The "save_return_value" could then include the return value

Answer (score 0):

Well, you assign to `values` the result of calling `print` which is `None`.
Then you simply print out the content of `values` which should print `None`.
Finally, you don't have any `return` statement and so your `education` function will always return `None`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the variables `(lt12ratio, edu12ratio,edumt12ratio, educollegeratio)` to `values`, not `print`.

If you want to print them, then you use `print(value)`. Finally, you need to `return` the `values` variable.

This is how your function should be:

```
def education():
    total = sum (df["CHILDNM"])
    edult12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 1, 0)
    nlt12=sum( edult12["CHILDNM"])
    edu12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 2, 0)
    n12= sum( edu12["CHILDNM"])
    edumt12 = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 3, 0)
    nmt12=sum( edumt12["CHILDNM"])
    educollege = df[['EDUC1','CHILDNM']].where(df['EDUC1'] == 4, 0)
    ncollege = sum( educollege["CHILDNM"])
    lt12ratio = nlt12/total
    edu12ratio = n12 / total
    edumt12ratio = nmt12 / total
    educollegeratio = ncollege/total

    values = (lt12ratio, edu12ratio,edumt12ratio, educollegeratio)
    print(values)
    return values
```