# I solve a code in Coursera using this method and it worked but they didn't accept it?

Tags: python

Modify the student_grade function using the format method, so that it returns the phrase "X received Y% on the exam". For example, `student_grade("Reed", 80)` should return "Reed received 80% on the exam".

**I solve this code just like this and I got the result but Coursera shows that is wrong answer why?**

```
def student_grade(name, grade):
    print("{name} received {grade}% on the exam".format(name=name,grade=grade))
    return ""
```

Here is your output:
Reed received 80% on the exam

Paige received 92% on the exam

Jesse received 85% on the exam

Not quite. Check that you're filling in the contents of the
`student_grade` function as requested.

Comment: You are *printing* the string, not returning it. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The question is asking you to return the string. What you are doing is printing it. Instead, do this:

```py
def student_grade(name, grade):
    return "{name} received {grade}% on the exam".format(name=name,grade=grade)
```

In order to pass values to functions, we use arguments. But what if we want to pass values back? Say we make a function, `add()`. It takes two numbers and wants to give the calling code their sum. If it just prints the result, the code that calls the function can't get it; printing is just a way of displaying things to the user.

That's where returns come in. A return value is what the calling code gets when it calls the function. To return in Python, we use the `return` statement. A kind of common misconception is that `return` itself is a function, and you need to put parentheses aroundt he value being returned. **That is not the case.** Thus, instead of printing the value, you should just return it, like so:

```py
def student_grade(name, grade):
    return "{name} received {grade}% on the exam".format(name=name,grade=grade)
```

Then the calling code can do things with the return value, like store it in a variable:

```py
grade = student_grade("Mark", 97)
```

And later, if it wants to, output it:

```py
print(grade)
```