# why we use print at some places and return at some other places while defining a function in python

Tags: python

```
def format_name():
  name = input("What is your name? \n")
  Name= name.title()
  #print(Name)  # this is correct 
  return Name    # this is not working
format_name()
```

I thought that print and return will give the same values but print is giving the output while return is not giving a output at all.

Comment: Try `print(format_name())`

Comment: Also: [What is the formal difference between "print" and "return"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7664779/13944524)

Comment: `print` allows the program to communicate information to the user. `return` allows one part of the program (a function) to communicate with another part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

print is to show a value to show a value to stdout ( in the console ) and return lets to send a value outside the function ( is the result of the function after doing its job ) and this result is the only value that the caller of the function will have.

see that to learn more about print and return: [https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#:~:text=Since%20everything%20in%20Python%20is,and%20even%20modules%20or%20packages](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#:%7E:text=Since%20everything%20in%20Python%20is,and%20even%20modules%20or%20packages).